# Question about jrat profiling

Tags: java, eclipse, profiling

I am working on a code which runs as a service. Basically it listens for input and produce output accordingly.

I am trying to profile a package using jrat. [We do not have a licence for Jprofiler and I couldnt set up the trial version to work properly].

I followed the instructions here:
http://transferer.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-use-jrat-in-eclipse.html
and
http://digiassn.blogspot.com/2008/01/java-using-jrat-under-eclipse.html

I am getting the .jrat output files but all I see is this:

> 001_JRat-LOG.jrat desktop% cat
>   001_JRat-LOG.jrat 
>   viewer="org.shiftone.jrat.ui.viewer.SimpleTextOutputViewBuilder"
>   JRat:INFO (Oct/18 17:15:32,769) (main)
>   RuntimeContextImpl - logfile created
>   JRat:INFO (Oct/18 17:15:32,769) (main)
>   RuntimeContextImpl - Running JRat
>   version 1-alpha2 - built on July 31
>   2006 JRat:INFO (Oct/18 17:15:32,770)
>   (main) Settings - string
>   'jrat.factory' =
>   'org.shiftone.jrat.provider.silent.SilentMethodHandler'
>   JRat:INFO (Oct/18 17:15:32,771) (main)
>   RootFactory - JRat creating root
>   handler factory... JRat:INFO (Oct/18
>   17:15:42,451) (JRat-JMX-Poller)
>   WaitingJmxRegistry - registering 6
>   mbean(s) JRat:INFO (Oct/18
>   17:15:42,451) (JRat-JMX-Poller)
>   ServerJmxRegistry - registerMBean
>   org.shiftone.jrat.core.jmx.info.JRatInfo@c5e9c
>   shiftone.jrat:service=org.shiftone.jrat.core.jmx.info.JRatInfo
>   JRat:INFO (Oct/18 17:15:42,453)
>   (JRat-JMX-Poller) ServerJmxRegistry -
>   registerMBean
>   org.shiftone.jrat.util.log.LoggingManager@11756a4
>   shiftone.jrat:service=org.shiftone.jrat.util.log.LoggingManager
>   JRat:INFO (Oct/18 17:15:42,453)
>   (JRat-JMX-Poller) ServerJmxRegistry -
>   registerMBean
>   org.shiftone.jrat.core.jmx.benchmark.Benchmark@b301f2
>   shiftone.jrat:service=org.shiftone.jrat.core.jmx.benchmark.Benchmark
>   JRat:INFO (Oct/18 17:15:42,453)
>   (JRat-JMX-Poller) ServerJmxRegistry -
>   registerMBean
>   Transformer[AsmInjectorStrategy(uses
>   http://asm.objectweb.org)]
>   shiftone.jrat:service=org.shiftone.jrat.inject.bytecode.Transformer
>   JRat:INFO (Oct/18 17:15:42,454)
>   (JRat-JMX-Poller) ServerJmxRegistry -
>   registerMBean
>   org.shiftone.jrat.core.shutdown.ShutdownRegistry@4be2cc
>   shiftone.jrat:service=org.shiftone.jrat.core.shutdown.ShutdownRegistry
>   JRat:INFO (Oct/18 17:15:42,454)
>   (JRat-JMX-Poller) ServerJmxRegistry -
>   registerMBean
>   FileOutputRegistry[PrintWriter[001_JRat-LOG.jrat]]
>   shiftone.jrat:service=org.shiftone.jrat.core.output.FileOutputRegistry
>   JRat:INFO (Oct/18 17:15:48,825)
>   (JRat-Shutdown) ShutdownRegistry -
>   shutting
>   down...[Transformer[AsmInjectorStrategy(uses
>   http://asm.objectweb.org)],
>   FileOutputRegistry[PrintWriter[001_JRat-LOG.jrat]]]
>   JRat:INFO (Oct/18 17:15:48,826)
>   (JRat-Shutdown) ShutdownRegistry -
>   shutting down
>   FileOutputRegistry[PrintWriter[001_JRat-LOG.jrat]]...
>   JRat:INFO (Oct/18 17:15:48,826)
>   (JRat-Shutdown) FileOutputRegistry -
>   closeFileOutputs
>   [PrintWriter[001_JRat-LOG.jrat]]
>   JRat:INFO (Oct/18 17:15:48,826)
>   (JRat-Shutdown) FileOutputRegistry -
>   closing :
>   PrintWriter[001_JRat-LOG.jrat]
>   JRat:INFO (Oct/18 17:15:48,826)
>   (JRat-Shutdown) FileOutputPrintWriter
>   - closing JRat:INFO (Oct/18 17:15:48,826) (JRat-Shutdown)
>   FileOutputRegistry - remove
>   PrintWriter[001_JRat-LOG.jrat]

Has someone used it before on linux ?. I am thinking since I am running this as a service .. after running my application I hit terminate button to stop my application [opposed to other applications which might terminate themselves after the work is done] .. this probably doesnt make the application exit gracefully and hence jrat does not produce a dump ?? This is just a blind guess though.

Thanks

P.S:
I am using eclipse
Java version 1.6.0_13

Edits:
Couldnt get this working , but tried Visualvm instead which works okay. 
However need to profile a remote appliaction,[Since I want to profile a part of my service and easy way to stress that part of the code and gets its number is from the server itself] so will look for something that is easy to use remotely.

Comment: Have you considered using JVisualVM?  It comes with the JDK.

Comment: Thnx .. I tried JVisualVM which worked fine. However it cannot be used with remote applications. This doc says "You cannot profile applications running on a remote host." https://visualvm.dev.java.net/gettingstarted.html?Java_VisualVM

Answer (score 0):

You could try BTrace, which installs as an agent on the application you are using. BTrace can be coupled with a remote visualizer to enable real time as well as historical charting of collected data.

Please refer to the following question for more info: [High Execution time on java methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071334/high-execution-time-on-java-methods/7505709#7505709)

Answer (score 0):

jrat hasn't been very active in the last years.

Maybe the best open-source approach is using AspectJ's JVMTI agent as explained in the following post: http://andrewclement.blogspot.com.br/2009/02/load-time-weaving-basics.html

You can write aspects that will be applied to classes as they are loaded by the JVM.