# High Execution time on java methods

Tags: java, linux, profiling, execution-time

I am running a java server on a CentOS 5.4 VPS. 
VPS stats: 
- 2.5GHz single core CPU
- 2GB of RAM
- OpenJDK 1.6 (tried Sun JDK 1.7 also)

I have been experiencing very high CPU usages from the java process. I then went and tried profiling the java process to see what was causing the slow down. I found that simple methods (like Random.nextInt(): 787ms) were taking 1000's of miliseconds to finish one call. Most of the methods should not take this long and are causing very high CPU usage on my server. Is this something wrong with CentOS? or Java? or is there something that I have not correctly configured on my VPS?

Comment: Depending on the random method being used, the machine may not have much entropy left and is waiting for more to appear before generating the next number.

Comment: Regardless... getting a random int should not take nearly a second.  In a virtual environment, it's possible that your virtual server is on heavily oversubscribed hardware, which you would not see using OS level tools like vmstat.  If you SSH into the box, does it feel responsive or sluggish?

Comment: It is quite fast, well, when java isn't taking 97% or so of the CPU. I have tested this on a

Comment: ** I have tested this on a VirtualPC (Ubuntu 10.04) on my computer and it seemed to have this issue also.  Also, My VPS is Xen based if that matters.

Comment: @Adam: `Random` does not use entropy, it is `SecureRandom` that uses entropy.

Comment: The server that I am using is a Minecraft Bukkit server. In the profiler I see a lot of time being used on Thread.sleep aswell. Is that bad programming practice? or is it part of the problem?     I found another two instances where Random.nextFloat took 149ms and Random.nextInt took 121ms  (these two were on a server on my computer (VirtualPC))

Comment: This seems to be happening quite frequently. I found another large user of CPU time: java.util.HashSet.iterator() (728ms) and java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeInt(int) (884ms)

Comment: how many threads?  32 or 64 bit (I suppose 32)?  running with -server?  what profiler are you using?

Comment: 68 threads (The "Total Created" keeps going up, Live threads stays the same), 64 bit (tested with -d64 and without), Using -server, I am using YourKit (The evaluation version)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding timings to your source code, try using a java agent like BTrace: http://kenai.com/projects/btrace which will let you get hold of the information you want, but without messing up your applications source code.

BTrace can be coupled with a visualizer, such as EurekaJ, (a project I have created to visualize BTtrace output): http://eurekaj.haagen.name

Other commercial profiling options are also available, such as JProfiler or YourKit, but they do come with a price tag.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reproduce your timings when you measure the processing time within the program, i.e. something like the following:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

/* Your code */

[...]    

long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

System.out.println("Measurement: " + time);
```

Also, what do you mean by "it is fast when Java is not taking 97% of the CPU"? Why is Java taking the 97% in the first place? Are there multiple threads running? Is your computation short or long running?

Comment: I will try some timing in a little bit. The "it is fast when Java is not taking 97% of the CPU" comment was saying that when these methods are taking this much time they use the majority of the CPU just to do simple tasks.